# WooCommerce custom field based on selected payment method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to add a field to the checkout only when a certain payment method is selected? My problem is, besides all the other customer details, I'm required to add the Spanish national number to PayPal payments, but not to the other payment methods.

Thank you for your help in advance!